# Autoscale cloud services from 0 instances?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-cloud-services

I have a set of cloud services with a customer who tends to use them in bursts: most of the day they sit idle and do nothing, and a couple of hours work like crazy.

Since I use Azure Service Bus, the scaling is seamless: I set the lower and the upper limits, everything is peachy, easy to define, and works very well (well done, Microsoft). But I still have 10 instances doing nothing most of the day, basically waiting. Is it somehow possible to define the lower limit of the autoscale as zero and not one?

Answer (score 1):

No. When we scale-out out cloud services, Microsoft creates replica of existing cloud service & when you scale-in they delete the instances.

If you happen to scale-in to minimum of zero. Microsoft deletes the deployment & they do not have master-piece to replicate from.

Comment: I'm not sure Microsoft replicates an existing cloud service. I remember modifying an instance manually and seeing a new one created without the modifications. Moreover, if you have differences in the instances, which one will be copied?

Comment: When you deploy a CSPCK it is extracted into a VHD and stored in a storage space by Azure Fabric Controller. The Azure FC attaches copies of the VHD with your code files to every machine provisioned for that particular web/worker role instance. If you RDP and change a particular instances environment the changes will not be persisted throughout the lifetime of the application. New instances will still have the code from your latest package deployed.

Comment: @daronyondem Thank you for correcting :-) so it seems provisioning to zero instance should be possible. The limitation of minimum one is mostly like marketing & strategic than technical, I believe.